# How to apply a top file when using salt-ssh and roster file

Tags: salt-stack

I'm new to salt, and I'm trying to use salt-ssh to manage hosts. I have the following roster file

~/salt/roster

```
pi:
  host: raspberypi1.local
  tty: True
  sudo: True
```

I have salt states

```
~/salt/states/docker.sls
```

I am able to apply the salt states by calling the state explicitly

```
sudo salt-ssh '*' -c . state.apply docker
```

How can I make it so that I don't have to call the state directly? I want the raspberypi1.local node to always run the docker state.

### Things I've tried

1. Make ~/salt/top.sls

```
base:
  'pi*':
    - docker
```

However the top.sls appears to be ignored by salt-ssh

I've tried editing `~/salt/Saltfile`  to point at a specific `file_roots`

```
salt-ssh:
  roster_file: /Users/foobar/salt/roster
  config_dir: /Users/foobar/salt
  log_file: /Users/foobar/salt/log.txt
  ssh_log_file: /Users/foobar/salt/ssh-log.txt
  file_roots:
    base:
      - /Users/foobar/salt/top.sls
```

Here file_roots also appears to be ignored.

Whats the proper way to tie states to nodes when using salt-ssh?

Answer (score 1):

I moved `~/salt/top.sls` to `~/salt/states/top.sls`, and removed `file_roots:` entirely from the Saltfile (it belongs in the master file). And now I am able to apply states like so:

```
sudo salt-ssh '*' -c . state.apply
```